# Change the icon when passing with the mouse, using leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I hope you can help me. I'm mapping dots with leaflet.
I need that, when passing with the mouse on the marker, the marker changes icon.
I managed to do it with an array in the following way:

```
baresPoblenou = [];
  baresPoblenou.push({ lat: 41.40288966232697, lng: 2.198766893752577, bar: 'Xorus', id: 'ChIJ0UGVLDyjpBIRdNcVCTidgPs', img: 'image/xorus.jpg', descp: 'HolaPhasellus finibus interdum aliquam. Nulla dignissim turpis id diam suscipit pellentesque. Pellentesque neque diam, laoreet eu arcu quis, porttitor convallis nisl. Donec sed hendrerit purus, sed euismod sem.<br>  Aenean sagittis dictum nibh, at rutrum lacus semper eget.', face: 'https://www.facebook.com/Xorus/', fono: '603 307 117', address: 'calle granada 90', web: 'xorus.html' });
  baresPoblenou.push({ lat: 41.3983979113559, lng: 2.204631508368948, bar: 'Blue Bar', id: 'ChIJpa-3z2qjpBIRUW4SwqLY7mk', img: 'image/bluebar.jpg', descp: 'Phasellus finibus interdum aliquam. Nulla dignissim turpis id diam suscipit pellentesque. Pellentesque neque diam, laoreet eu arcu quis, porttitor convallis nisl. Donec sed hendrerit purus, sed euismod sem. Aenean sagittis dictum nibh, at rutrum lacus semper eget.', face: 'https://www.facebook.com/bluebar/', fono: '93 280 90 59', address: ' Pallars, 122', web: '' });
  baresPoblenou.push({ lat: 41.39684988162788, lng: 2.192088531196873, bar: 'D9', id: 'ChIJnVDdoRmjpBIR8Ra7Fpj8nxE', img: 'image/d9.jpg', descp: 'Phasellus finibus interdum aliquam. Nulla dignissim turpis id diam suscipit pellentesque. Pellentesque neque diam, laoreet eu arcu quis, porttitor convallis nisl. Donec sed hendrerit purus, sed euismod sem. Aenean sagittis dictum nibh, at rutrum lacus semper eget.', face: 'https://www.facebook.com/LaTavernicola/', fono: '93 667 74 54', address: 'Rambla de Poblenou 44-46', web: '' });


  var iconDefault = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'image/icoAzul.png'
  })
  var iconDinamic = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'image/icoPlomo.png'
  })
  var iconDinamic2 = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'image/icoVioleta.png'
  })

  for (i = 0; i < baresPoblenou.length; i++) {
    marcas = L.marker([baresPoblenou[i].lat, baresPoblenou[i].lng], {
      title: baresPoblenou[i].bar,
      icon: iconDefault,
    });
    marcas.addTo(map);

    marcas.on('mouseover', function () {
      this.setIcon(iconDinamic)
    });
    marcas.on('mouseout', function () {
      this.setIcon(iconDefault)
    });
    marcas.on('mousedown', function () {
      this.setIcon(iconDinamic2)
    });
    marcas.on('mouseup', function () {
      this.setIcon(iconDefault)
    });
  };
```

But now I need to do it using a GeoJson and not an array.
This is my code:

```
baresPoblenou = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('data/farmacias.geojson', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    minZoom: 14,
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
      popupContent = "<b>" + feature.properties.NOM + "</b><br>" + feature.properties
        .CARRCADAST + " " + feature.properties.DOORNUM + "</b>";
      layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    },
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
      marcas = L.marker(latlng, {
        title: "hola",
        icon: iconDefault
      });
      return marcas
    },
    }).addTo(map)
```

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your event listeners before returning the marker

```
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
  marcas = L.marker(latlng, {
    title: "hola",
    icon: iconDefault
  });


  marcas.on('mouseover', function () {
    this.setIcon(iconDinamic)
  });
  marcas.on('mouseout', function () {
    this.setIcon(iconDefault)
  });
  marcas.on('mousedown', function () {
    this.setIcon(iconDinamic2)
  });
  marcas.on('mouseup', function () {
    this.setIcon(iconDefault)
  });
  return marcas
```